# When putting a number before a word in a TextBlock causes it to display first the word then the number.

Tags: wpf, string, textblock

When I do this:

```
 porVer = new TextBlock()
        {    
             porVer.Text = "3 Episodes";   
        };
```

In my app it displays like this "Epsiodes 3" and I can't figure out why.

Thank You

Comment: I suspect you're probably setting the value to `Epsiodes 3` (typo?) somewhere. Try and replicate your problem in a brand new project containing just that one `TextBlock` and see if the behaviour persists.

Comment: Searching for the text "Episodes 3" in your code may also help.

Comment: **Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for.** - What are you trying to do?